# Order of events triggerd by Backbone.Router when using navigate

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using Backbone's "all" event to catch all route events in my app in order to log the page views. This works well as long as I don't use `navigate` to manually trigger a route.
In the following example, I forward the user from the `dashboard` route to the `login` route. Backbone fires the event AFTER the route callback is executed, leading to the following output:

```
showDashboard
showLogin
route:showLogin
tracking:/login
route:showDashboard
tracking:/login
```

Obviously this is not what I want. I know I could call `showLogin` instead of using `navigate` to trigger the login route and this is what I am doing right now, but I would like to know why the order of the events is not the same than the order of the triggered callbacks.

Here is my router (shortened):

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "/login": "showLogin",
        "": "showDashboard",
    },
    initialize: function() {
        return this.on('all', this.trackPageview);
    },
    trackPageview: function(eventName) {
        console.log(eventName);
        var url = Backbone.history.getFragment();
        console.log('tracking: ' + url);
    },
    showDashboard: function() { 
        console.log('showDashboard');
        // check if the user is logged in etc.
        this.navigate('#/login', { trigger: true });
    },
    showLogin: function() {
        console.log('showLogin');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Backbone's `Router` is actually very simple, and if you read [the code](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js) you'll see the following in it's constructor:

```
this._bindRoutes();
this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
```

`_bindRoutes` attaches all your routes as you expect, and it does this *before* your `initialize` function gets called. So your binding will always fire after Backbone's does.

You're probably going to be better off finding another way to do this.

You could call a `before` type function yourself in your routes to do stuff like track pageviews/etc. Or maybe you could just override `route`, track your pageview and then make sure to call Backbone's implementation with something like `Backbone.Router.prototype.route.call(arguments);`